# unable to push docker image to gcr.io

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

Here is a very simple requirement.
I prepared a docker image on my Mac and wish to push it to GCR. 
Tried below steps..

```
gcloud auth configure-docker
docker login gcr.io
docker push gcr.io/[project-id]/gcloud:latest
```

```
The push refers to repository [gcr.io/[project-id]/gcloud]
0141ab2d5898: Retrying in 1 second
522a3d37badb: Retrying in 1 second
0b1ee8a19f71: Retrying in 1 second
0cb89ac95352: Retrying in 1 second
c27a33c2a613: Retrying in 2 seconds
1416f891501a: Waiting
2edebac67fd2: Waiting
cff7468ca6ac: Waiting
7d105a69bdfc: Waiting
8607e6c66303: Waiting
dc87e12495f4: Waiting
c3c5e6948ef3: Waiting
5f70bf18a086: Waiting
b2f56e492d5b: Waiting
861512eb6ef5: Waiting
876201329b4b: Waiting
unknown: Token exchange failed for project '[project-id]'. Bad Request.
```

Does anybody can suggest on this issue?

Comment: Try to discover this answer https://serverfault.com/a/961093

Comment: thank you, I tried before...but the problem still exist

Comment: Does the account you use have storage admin permission? And what is location type for your `artifacts.[project_id]...` bucket?

Comment: Is your system python using python3? I've run into issues where gcloud only works with python2 and this surfaces as an error when I'm trying to docker push an image.

Comment: @EmilGi . yes, it has storage admin permission. how to figure out location type if the gcr is empty

Comment: yes, I m using py3 on my mac. would you like to post your error here?

Comment: Check your organization policies. It might be that you are not allowed to create multi-regional buckets in GCS. When pushing to GCR it tries to create such bucket and if not allowed to do so fails. Check this https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling#push_the_tagged_image_to

Comment: Is your issue resolved?If yes, can you  post the procedure you've followed as Solution and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `gcloud auth activate-service-account [SERVICE_ACCOUNT]` instead `docker login gcr.io`

I think it is a better way than `docker login`.

Comment: yes, I tied to activate infra SA instead of my own account. Fail to push with same error.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the official [guide](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling) and check everything from "Before you begin" section.

Also, you must add registry name and image name as a tag to your image. You can find more details [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/quickstart) and [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-push-docker-image-to-google-private-container-registry-a2b58615e795).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I do read these two documents before...  But didn’t help me... And I checked IAM as well.

Comment: Could you update your first post and include there all the checks and results? It looks like you missed some small detail, but it's hard to found without additional information.

Comment: sure, will do that soon

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the added precondition that there was not yet an existing image in the registry.

If no image exists yet, the GCR storage backend (a GCS bucket) also doesn't exist yet.

Make sure that this bucket can be created by the user that's logged into `gcloud`. In my case, there was an org policy prohibiting multi-region buckets, which is the type of bucket that's needed for GCR.

You can check if this is the root cause of your issue by going into the project activities, where you'll see a failing bucket creation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which made some advance for me:

- Enable the registry API, see [this page](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/enable-service)

> Enable the API from [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=containerregistry.googleapis.com&_ga=2.132485261.2014492575.1633319491-1212768905.1633105044) or with the following gcloud command

However, don't use the cloud command. I tried. It's a lie.

Now I have another error: `name unknown: Buckets(projectname,artifacts.projectid.appspot.com)`

Progressing...